# $\int_{G}E[X|\mathcal{G}]dP = \int_{G}XdP$ implies that $E[X|\mathcal{G}]=X$

Tags: conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, sigma-algebra

I need to prove that for $\mathcal{G} = \mathcal{F}$ (so the largest sigma field), $\int_{G}E[X|\mathcal{G}]dP = \int_{G}XdP\, \forall G \in \mathcal{G}$ implies that $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = X$ almost everywhere.

My attempt is this: $\int_{G}E[X|\mathcal{G}]dP = \int_{G}XdP = \int_{G}\left(E[X|\mathcal{G}] - X\right)dP $, but then where do I go from there?

I know that if we were talking about probabilities and not expectations, $P[A|\mathcal{F}] = I_{A}$ (where $I_{A}$ is the indicator function for $A$) because knowing the outcome of $\mathcal{F}$ is to know whether or not an event $A$ has occurred, but I don't know how to apply that to the above integrals to give me the $E[X|\mathcal{F}] = X$ that I need.

Could somebody please help me? Thank you ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the uniqueness of conditional expectation. By definition $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ must be $\mathcal{F}$ measurable and satisfies:

$\int_G E[X|\mathcal{F}]=\int_G XdP,$

for all $G\in\mathcal{F}$. As well, clearly $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable. So $E[X|\mathcal{F}]=X$ satisfies the above.

To prove uniqueness, note that the above implies $\int_G (E[X|\mathcal{F}]-X)dP=0$. This must hold for all $G\in\mathcal{F}$. Since $Y:=E[X|\mathcal{F}]-X$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$, this implies that $Y=0$ almost everywhere. Otherwise, if say $Y>0$ on some $g\in\mathcal{F}$ with $P(g)>0$, then $\int_gYdP>0$, which is a contradiction. Similarly for $Y<0$.

Comment: I guess if you wanted to show the same thing but for the trivial sigma field (i.e., that $E[X|\mathcal{G}]=E[X]$ a.e.), it would be the same idea?

Comment: @Jeff: Uniqueness holds for any sub-sigma algebra conditional expectation. But, be careful, the above already assumes the original sigma field, when we claim $E[X|\mathcal{F}]=X$, because the r.h.s. must be $\mathcal{F}$ measurable.

Comment: so we would just assume that the RHS would be $\mathcal{G}$ measurable in that case?

Comment: so if X is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, the only things it could be are $\emptyset$ or $\Omega$ if $\mathcal{G}$ is the trivial sigma-field.

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry I think I misunderstood your comment. That's right, it would have to be constant in the trivial sigma field.

Comment: Now, if $G = \emptyset$, then we would have $\int_{\emptyset}E[X|\mathcal{G}]dP = 0 = \int_{\emptyset}XdP$, so then how do we get from that that $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, though? *sorry, had a bit of a brain fart moment there*

Comment: Null sets must satisfy $P(\emptyset)=0$, otherwise your probability measure wouldn't be finite!